# ERROR AL CORRER MI PROYECTO (Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again)

Tags: java, selenium, test-ng

Cuando intento correr mi proyecto de prueba (Selenium y testNG) me sale este error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

Ya revisé todas las librerias y aún no he podido resolverlo. Agradezco en lo que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Hola @LauraAlvarez. El rastreo de pila contiene información importante y útil que nos puede ayudar a dar con el problema. El rastreo que has colocado indica lo siguiente: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException`. Este tipo de excepciones sucede cuando no se puede encontrar la clase que se está tratando de  cargar y se debe principalmente a que alguna librería [no ha sido cargada](http://es.wikihow.com/a%C3%B1adir-un-jar-a-un-proyecto-en-eclipse-(java)) en el **classpath** del proyecto.

Answer (score 2):

La clase `ParameterException` no se encuentra:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException

me parece que falta instalar [**jCommander**](http://jcommander.org/), si usas `gradle` agrega esta dependencia:

```
compile "com.beust:jcommander:1.48"
```

si usas `Maven` agrega:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
  <version>1.48</version>
</dependency>
```

o usa el .jar y agregalo dentro del folder `/lib`, puedes descargarlo **[aquí!](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjcommanderjar.htm)**

Answer (score 0):

Verifica en el `jcommander.jar` que esa clase `ParameterException` esta ahí! En este caso no esta por la excepción que lanza, tienes que buscar una versión de la librería mas actualizada o mas vieja, depende de tu proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrega otra versión de java porque puedes estar utilizando una que te moleste porque a mí me molesto la JDK 1.8. Por eso, puse la otra y me compiló sin problemas.

Le das clic secundario al proyecto y te vas a run.