# A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again when execute a jar

Tags: java, eclipse, excepciones, jar, jni

Tengo un proyecto en Eclipse, funciona perfectamente, lo exporto a un jar file para correrlo sin eclipse y me da el error que se ve en el titulo en una ventana emergente, acepto y me sale una segunda ventana que dice a Java Exception has occured.
Alguna idea de por qué funciona dentro de eclipse y no fuera?

Comment: con qué versión de java estás compilando tu proyecto y con cuál estás corriendo el jar?

Comment: Creo que sería esto pero no estoy muy familiarizado con java aún, jdk-12.0.1 y jre1.8.0_271

Comment: Añado, en el projecto, en java build path dice JRE System Library [JavaSE-14]

Comment: o esto otro? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25518/error-al-correr-mi-proyecto-error-a-jni-error-has-occurred-please-check-your?rq=1 posiblemente estás compilando con una (java12) y corriendo con otra anterior (java8).

Comment: Si vi esas preguntas pero no puse solucionarlo, ahora buscare como hacer coincidir ambas versiones, debería compilarlo con java8 no?